# Toggle multiple Checkbox at once

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onclick

I have these checkboxs:

```
'<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" value="checked" class= "toggleable">'; 
'<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" value="checked" class= "toggleable">'; 
'<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox3" value="checked" class= "toggleable">';
```

Which I can check or uncheck by clinking on them. 
 Now I am trying to add one more checkbox, which will check or uncheck all previous checkbox at once when clicking.

```
'<input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck_all" value="false" id="id_check_uncheck_all">'
```

What is the JS code to execute when clicking the checkbox to check or uncheck all checkbox "toggleable" at once?

Comment: Just add an event handler that when clicked will select the rest of the boxes and change their `.checked` state to match its own. Simple enough. This isn't a code writing service. What have you written and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example on how to make this work in pure JavaScript.

```js
var checkAll = document.getElementById("id_check_uncheck_all");
checkAll.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var checked = this.checked;
  var otherCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleable");
  [].forEach.call(otherCheckboxes, function(item) {
    item.checked = checked;
  });
});
```

```html
<label for="id_check_uncheck_all">Select All</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck_all" value="false" id="id_check_uncheck_all">
<br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" value="checked" class= "toggleable"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" value="checked" class= "toggleable"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox3" value="checked" class= "toggleable">
```

Comment: Nice. FYI, it's a little shorter if you pass `this` as an argument after the callback, then do `item.checked = this.checked`.

Comment: @squint nice tip--I've never thought of doing it that way. I am going to leave the answer as is though because I think it is simpler for a novice.

Comment: @user1106925 I don't get what you are saying, would you mind modifying dave's code and show what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Just verify through JS that if particular `checkbox` checked. It has to check all of them.

**JS Demo Below: UPDATE**

Just added `id` to your inputs.

```js
function checkAll(x) {
  if(x.checked == true){
   document.getElementById('c1').checked = true;
   document.getElementById('c2').checked = true;
   document.getElementById('c3').checked = true;      
  }else{
   document.getElementById('c1').checked = false;
   document.getElementById('c2').checked = false;
   document.getElementById('c3').checked = false;    
  }
}
```

```html
Multiple Check Box Below:
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" value="checked" class="toggleable" id="c1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" value="checked" class="toggleable" id="c2">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox3" value="checked" class="toggleable" id="c3">
</br>
Check below to Check them all:
</br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck_all" onchange='checkAll(this);' value="false" id="id_check_uncheck_all">
```

**JQuery Demo below:**

```js
$('#checkAll').click(function () {    
     $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);    
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" > Check All
</br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem"> Item 1
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem"> Item 2 
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem"> Item3
```

Comment: I see no indication that the OP is using jQuery. You don't need large libraries to accomplish simple tasks.

Comment: @squint My bad, you must just had comment i would have known.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $(".toggleable").click(function() {
      
        var checkboxes = $(".toggleable");
      
        if($(this).prop("checked")) checkboxes.prop("checked",true);
        else checkboxes.prop("checked",false);
      
    })
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" class= "toggleable">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" class= "toggleable"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox3" class= "toggleable">
```