# javascript toggle multiple checkbox by class name

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm not familiar (at least) with JavaScript and I need it to toggle multiple checkbox with one other.
I've grab a code from that [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510447/toggle-multiple-checkbox-at-once) which works great !

```js
var checkAll = document.getElementById("id_check_uncheck_all");
checkAll.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var checked = this.checked;
  var otherCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleable");
  [].forEach.call(otherCheckboxes, function(item) {
    item.checked = checked;
  });
});
```

```html
<body>
  <label for="id_check_uncheck_all">Select All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck_all" value="false" id="id_check_uncheck_all">
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" value="checked1" class="toggleable">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" value="checked2" class="toggleable">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox3" value="checked3" class="toggleable">
</body>
```

but...
I need to use it for few groups more in my page (and site) and I wonder how to turn it on a function which will use "this" and the needed class parameter on the main checkbox like :

```js
function checkAllBox(ref, classname) {
  var checkAll = document.getElementById(ref);
  checkAll.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    var otherCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll(classname);
    [].forEach.call(otherCheckboxes, function(item) {
      item.checked = checked;
    });
  });
};
```

```html
<body>

  <label for="id_check_uncheck_all">Select All</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck_all" value="false" id="id_check_uncheck_all" onclick="checkAllBox('id_check_uncheck_all','toggleable')">
  <br/>

  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" value="checked1" class="toggleable">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" value="checked2" class="toggleable">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox3" value="checked3" class="toggleable">

</body>
```

I also have a function which also work well, but with checkbox-target name instead of checkbox-target class, which can be confused for other php method :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkAllBox(ref, name) {
          var form = ref;

          while (form.parentNode && form.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'form') { form = form.parentNode; }

          var elements = form.getElementsByTagName('input');

          for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && elements[i].name == name) {
              elements[i].checked = ref.checked;
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
```

I've try many modifications but none seems to work (but I was blind in what I've try because of my lack of knowledge in JavaScript)... The comment on my "inspiration" stackoverflow page suggest to do so but I can not achieve this perf...

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: I have made a snippet of your first two code blocks.  Perhaps you can edit the second to put ALL the HTML in and ALL the related JavaScript you have tried there so we have a clear understanding of what you have tried and your one challenge with that.

Comment: ALSO note I DID fix your malformed HTML in the first example - I jumped to an assumption that was just a copy/paste issue but if not perhaps add clarity there.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss How quick you are ! Here is where I am : I've modify my second code to put my "full" code. I just don't know how to use "This" argument so I've try to call the function with the main checkbox id... However, it won't work anymore ! Thx for the snippet, it is very usefull, but i didn't know how to deal with !

Comment: You might be interested in the last example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467796/5351721. It's a more semantic way to handle nested groups of checkboxes, and uses the "indeterminate" state for when part of a group is checked.

Comment: Thx ! It's true but it does not what I really expected to do. I've spend times to find a correct way, with code exemple, wich actually work and I would like to share my solution to answer my updated question : toggle multiple checkbox by class name.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to delegate from the container and check/uncheck ALL if  all the children are checked/unchecked also.

Lots of comments and "extra" code to show what is where/what in the  code parts.

I commented out one part of the code since you asked about "this" but not used here.

```js
var checkAll = document
  .querySelectorAll('.checkbox-container input[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach((checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      let checkTarget = event.currentTarget;
      //let checkThis = this;
      // always true: console.log(checkThis == checkTarget);

      let container = checkTarget.closest('.checkbox-container');
      let checkAll = container.querySelector(".check-all"); //assumes ONE checkall per container
      let haveCheckedAll = checkTarget == checkAll;
      let isAllChecked = checkAll.checked;
      let otherCheckboxes = [...container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"].toggleable')];
      if (!haveCheckedAll) {
        let areAllDetailedChecked = otherCheckboxes.filter((item) => {
          return item.checked;
        }).length == otherCheckboxes.length;
        checkAll.checked = areAllDetailedChecked;
      } else {
        otherCheckboxes.forEach((item) => {
          item.checked = isAllChecked;
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.checkbox-container,
.check-all-container {
  border: 1px solid #00FF00;
}

.checkbox-container {
  border-color: #0000ff;
  margin: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="checkbox-container">First
    <div class="check-all-container">
      <label for="id_check_uncheck_all">Select All</label>
      <input class="check-all" type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck_all" value="false" id="id_check_uncheck_all">
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" value="checked1" class="toggleable">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" value="checked2" class="toggleable">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox3" value="checked3" class="toggleable">
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox-container">Second
    <div class="check-all-container">
      <label for="check_uncheck_allTwo">Select All</label>
      <input class="check-all" type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck_allTwo" value="false" id="check_uncheck_allTwo">
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" value="checked1" class="toggleable">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox2" value="checked2" class="toggleable">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox3" value="checked3" class="toggleable">
  </div>
</body>
```